# Insert first column spinner into a table

Tags: android

I've a table (Categories) wich two columns (_id, name).

I've a spinner that shows the column name.

Now, I need to insert the column: "_id" into another table...but I don't know how to do it.

Any suggestions?

---

I paste the code I'm using:

```
public Cursor recuperaCategoria()
    {
    final UsuariosSQLiteHelper usdbh =new UsuariosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBLlistaCompra", null, 1);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();
    String tableName = "Categorias";
    String[] columns = {"_id","Nombre"};

    return db.query(tableName, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

public void recCatSpinner() {
        final Spinner addCatSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spIdCategoria);
        catCursor = recuperaCategoria();
        catCursor.moveToPosition(1);
        catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
        addCatSpinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
        if (catCursor.moveToFirst()) { 
          do { 

             catAdapter.add(catCursor.getString(1)); 
             Valor = catCursor.getString(1); 
             Log.v("valor Add Cat 100", Valor);
         } 
          while (catCursor.moveToNext()); 
            int id = catCursor.getInt(0);
            String name = catCursor.getString(1);

          Log.v("Dentro cursor","1");
          if (db != null) { 
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),catCursor.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          db.close(); 
          } 
        } 
        startManagingCursor(catCursor);
        //catCursor.close();
        addCatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view2, int pos, long id) {
                        //recID();
                        valor = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                        Log.v("valor Add Cat", valor);

                        }
                  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                       // view.setText("nada");
                    }
                });
        catCursor.close();
}
```

I'd like that when I select one item from spinner (it shows the column "Nombre"), I save into one variable the first column from cursor "_id".

Comment: If you mean SQLite db table, then write an sql script which will read ids and add them to another table. Or narrow your question.

Comment: Thanks, it's a sqllite. i'm writing a new cursor with the name selected at spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read values to collection then write a script to insert them to another taBLE

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = { _id };
String selection = "column_name" + "=?";
String orderBy = "_id ASC";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "something" };
String groupBy = null;
String having = null;

Cursor cursor = db.query("table_name", "columns", selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);

while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

   int id = cursor.getInt(0);
   String name = cursor.getString(1);

   // Add values to a collection
}
if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
```

---

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

for(int id : idCollection) {

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("_id",   id);

  try {

    int id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
  }
  catch (SQLException sqlEx) {

    // do something with exception
  } 
}

if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
```